# How do I use add_resource with Eve application?

Tags: python, flask, eve

I have an Eve application running and I wanted to reorganize it (just to follow best practices) so that it looks similar to a flask application directory structure.

I tried to use something like this from flask

```py
from flask_restful import Api

app=Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)
api.add_resource(resources.UserRegistration, '/registration')
```

like this in Eve:

```py
from eve import Eve

app = Eve(auth=CustomAuth)
api = Api(app)
api.add_resource(resources.UserRegistration, '/registration')
```

I get the following error while starting the Eve application:

**Traceback:**

```
File "/var/www/flask-api/views.py", line 1, in <module>
    from run import app
  File "/var/www/flask-api/run.py", line 22, in <module>
    api.add_resource(resources.UserRegistration, '/registration')
  File "/var/www/django/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/flask_restful/__init__.py", line 382, in add_resource
    self._register_view(self.app, resource, *urls, **kwargs)
  File "/var/www/django/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/flask_restful/__init__.py", line 448, in _register_view
    app.add_url_rule(rule, view_func=resource_func, **kwargs)
  File "/var/www/django/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 98, in wrapper_func
    return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/var/www/django/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1274, in add_url_rule
    rule = self.url_rule_class(rule, methods=methods, **options)
  File "/var/www/django/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/routing.py", line 640, in __init__
    if not string.startswith("/"):
AttributeError: 'functools.partial' object has no attribute 'startswith'
```

My `resources.py` file looks something like this:

```py
from flask_restful import Resource

class UserRegistration(Resource):
    def post(self):
        return {'message': 'User registration'}
```

Comment: Have you tried using blueprints?

Comment: @gcw frankly, i am new to flask so i have no clue how blueprints are used. Will definitely take a look though. thanks!

Comment: Check this https://docs.python-eve.org/en/stable/snippets/hooks_blueprints.html. It is not about blueprints, but shows how to use it also.

Comment: Blueprints worked perfectly for me. Thanks a ton @gcw

Comment: Great, I will write it as an answer since it solved your organization problem. It may help others too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use Flask Blueprints to organize your routes in different files and then register them within the application. Check this eve documentation that mentions blueprints: https://docs.python-eve.org/en/stable/snippets/hooks_blueprints.html.

More on Flask blueprints from Flask's documentation: https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/blueprints/